# Define a servicemix xml for a websocket server

Tags: java, xml, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I try to develop a websocket server using just XML in servicemix, but I can't get it working. Not even close.

I have a rest based example that I would like to turn into a websocket server.

I already tried a few things but the result is always that i get a 404 back of no connection at all. I assume that i have to register a websocket service as I did with the http service, but I cannot find any documentation how to do that in a similar way as in my example.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
  xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

  <osgi:reference id="httpService" interface="org.osgi.service.http.HttpService"/>

  <bean id="SelectCamelServlet"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet">
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
    init-method="register"
    destroy-method="unregister">
    <property name="alias" value="/cmsa"/>
    <property name="httpService" ref="httpService"/>
    <property name="servlet" ref="SelectCamelServlet"/>
    <property name="servletName" value="SelectCamelServlet"/>
  </bean>
<bean id="datasource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres"/>
    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
    <property name="password" value="postgres"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Configure the Camel SqlComponent to use the JDBC datasource. -->
  <bean id="sqlcomponent"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Configure a camelContext with logic. -->
  <camelContext useMDCLogging="true" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

    <restConfiguration bindingMode="json" component="servlet">
      <endpointProperty key="servletName" value="SelectCamelServlet" />
      <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="false"/>
    </restConfiguration>

    <rest path="/density">
      <get uri="">
        <to pattern="InOut" uri="direct:get" />
      </get>
    </rest>

    <!-- Configure a route that reads an argument from http (GET),
         uses that in a query and returns the dataset in JSON format. -->
    <route id="oefenen_route">

      <from uri="direct:get"/>

      <!-- Specify content-type to control the body's character encoding.
           If this is omitted, the body's data is base64 encoded. -->
     <setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
        <simple>application/json; charset=utf-8</simple>
      </setHeader>

      <!-- Run the query. -->
      <to uri="sqlcomponent:select sensor, aantal as density from cmsa order by sensor?
               outputType=SelectList&amp;
               greedy=true&amp;
               useIterator=false"/>

    </route>
  </camelContext>
</beans>
```

I solved my own question as follows:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
  xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
  xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
  xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
     http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd">

  <osgi:reference id="wsService" interface="org.osgi.service.http.HttpService"/>

  <bean id="CamelWsServlet"
    class="org.apache.camel.component.atmosphere.websocket.CamelWebSocketServlet">
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.servlet.osgi.OsgiServletRegisterer"
    init-method="register"
    destroy-method="unregister">
    <property name="alias" value="/websocket"/>
    <property name="httpService" ref="wsService"/>
    <property name="servlet" ref="CamelWsServlet"/>
    <property name="servletName" value="CamelWsServlet"/>
  </bean>

  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="atmosphere-websocket:///hola"/>
        <to uri="atmosphere-websocket:///hola?sendToAll=true"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second listing answers my question. I did almost the same as in the first listing, except the the used class is different. This works fine if I put this in the servicemix deploy directory as an xml file.